# How old is the Spear of Destiny, and what significance does it have?

Tags: comics, top-cow-universe

In The Magdalena #3, a female demon (after being sliced in two and attacking again as two gross tentacle-sprouted mini-demons) says, "The trinket you carry was *old* before before Christ was ever nailed to the cross... *and it's still not enough!*"

How old is the Spear of Destiny in the Top Cow universe? What does it have to do with Christ - that is, was it just coincidence that he was stabbed by an artifact (one of the thirteen Artifacts in the Top Cow universe)?

Comment: Not familiar with the canon, but I've seen other canons link the Spear of Destiny with the Spear of Lugh (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spear_of_Lugh#Lug.27s_Spear)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not to sound too cheeky, but:

**As an Artifact, it is as old as time itself**

The Artifacts are significant [because they end universes](http://witchblade.wikia.com/wiki/Thirteen_artifacts):

> Separately, 13 Artifacts guide the fate of the universe. Together, 13 artifacts will end the universe.

And by the time we are introduced to Witchblade:

> [There is already a survivor of the previous universe](http://www.comicvine.com/curator/4005-15348/).

So we know "this" universe is not the first, and the artifacts have been around since at least the creation of that (since they existed in the prior).

Answer (score 1):

- How old is the Spear of Destiny in the Top Cow universe?

  I wasn't able to find any in-TopCow mentions of the age, but not sure that my search was complete.
- What does it have to do with Christ - that is, was it just coincidence that he was stabbed by an artifact (one of the thirteen Artifacts in the Top Cow universe)?

  > The Spear of Destiny is not the original form of the artifact, but it had remained in its current aspect for more than two millennia. Reshaped into the spear that pierced Christ's side as he hung upon the cross, **it had been wielded by an incarnation of the Magdalena ever since. Descended from the bloodline of Christ, one daughter of each generation serves as the Church's warrior against supernatural foes**. (Source: http://www.comicvine.com/spear-of-destiny/18-47001/)

Comment: The second bit doesn't so much answer "is there a reason someone used artifact to pierce the side of Christ?" as "what is the Spear of Destiny?".

Comment: @IanPugsley - true. There does not seem to be much info beyond that though.